How to use JSONiq in a python program?
How can I use JSONiq to query JSON objects in a python program running on my PC?
I have managed to use JSONiq in a Jupyter Notebook running inside Visual Studio Code, but I'm interested in using JSONiq in a regular python program (*.py), rather than a notebook (*.ipynb).

Why do you think the use would be any different?

Because it uses line and cell magic to run when you are in a Jupyter Notebook with a Python kernel, you'd use it the same as you would any other magic, I suspect? See 'How to run IPython magic from a script'. Make sure you try the current syntax, see this comment.

@Wayne: Thanks. I've tried the solution in the post you linked to, but the function call get_ipython() returns None, and this causes an error.

@Barmar Because when I copy-and-pasted from the Jupyter notebook I got the following error message: %load_ext rumbledb SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

I see you marked it as solved using Ghislain's solution. That seems to do at the core what I was trying to say, but has more current code with proper syntax. Or maybe more flexible code to accomplish what I was trying to encourage. Plus, definitely thorough because also has the package specific stuff you'd need to get past the initial approach I was encouraging. .... I'd have to look more into why get_ipython() maybe had issues.

@Wayne I managed to get it working inside a Jupyter Notebook.

What about using from IPython.core.magic import Magics, cell_magic, magics_class from here? That worked in Python directly?

@Wayne Yes, if you avoid the magic altogether, it can be run in a non-notebook Python program.

Okay. However, I more meant that import step works for you? So that establishes you can access IPython from your Python. So I'm not understanding why from IPython import get_ipython on a line followed by ip = get_ipython()  in Python won't work?

@Wayne I too am not understanding this.

Okay. It works everywhere I tried in Python just now (three in total; one local and two remote with various versions) & so it is definitely odd. Thankfully Ghislain's more full featured option got you past that.

It is possible to communicate between Python (outside of a notebook) and a running RumbleDB instance (JSONiq engine) via HTTP. This can be done by copy-pasting the same code that is running in Jupyter notebooks to support the %jsoniq magic into your own Python script. It is all open-source and available here:
https://github.com/RumbleDB/pyrumble/blob/main/src/rumbledb/rumbledb.py
You can, of course, adapt the signature of the function to your liking and needs.
Running the server (same as for notebooks)
Like for Jupyter notebooks, the RumbleDB server can run anywhere (locally on your own laptop, or on a cloud provider such as Amazon EMR, etc) as long as the firewall settings make the port accessible. The command to run a server on, say, port 8001 is:
spark-submit path-to-rumbledb-1.21.jar serve -p 8001

It is recommended to make sure only you have access to the port (e.g., by running locally and with a firewall, or by setting up IP restrictions on the cloud provider) because this is a relatively simple implementation with no security in mind.
Passing small amounts of data
Small amounts of data can be directly passed from Python to JSONiq through the query, e.g. by embedding some JSON into a global or let variable declaration in the JSONiq query string passed to RumbleDB.
Small amounts of data can be passed from JSONiq to Python in the query results, which are sent via HTTP back to Python in the response body.
Passing large amounts of data
Larger amounts of data (csv, JSON Lines, text, etc) can be passed from Python to JSONiq by saving them on any file system both have access to (local, S3, HDFS, etc), and then reading them with JSONiq with the appropriate URI.
Large amounts of data can be passed back from JSONiq to Python if the cloud provider supports the Apache Livy standard, in which case you can copy-paste this code instead. This runs the jar as a single job for every request, and it is then possible to specify the output path RumbleDB needs to write the output to. It can be TBs or even PBs of data if running on a cluster and writing back to cloud storage.
We do have future plans to attempt a tighter integration of JSONiq into Python (which would "embed" RumbleDB in Python for a more natural interaction via memory rather than via a file system), but have no clear dates at this point.

Thanks. A tighter integration of JSONiq into Python would be very much appreciated. JSONiq is fantastic, btw. It gets it right (unlike other JSON query languages).

I am delighted to hear this! This is motivating us even more to push up the priority. Also thank you for the nice words on JSONiq!

import json
import requests

# Replace the port number
# by the port you used
# to run rumbledb from the command line,
# in my case:
# spark-submit rumbledb-1.21.0-for-spark-3.5.jar serve -p 9090
__RUMBLEDB_PORT__ = 9090

# Code adapted from the rumbldb source code
# for the jsoniq cell magic at
# https://github.com/RumbleDB/pyrumble/blob/main/src/rumbledb/rumbledb.py
# as suggested by Ghislain in his answer above
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/78768053/1818935
# The _python_ value corresponding to the JSON value
# that is meant to be the query's target
# should be passed as the parameter target.
# Use three consecutive dollar symbols: $$$
# to represent the target JSON value in the query.
def jsoniq(target:str, query:str) -> list:
    resolved_query = query.replace('$$$', json.dumps(target))

    rumbledb_url = f'http://localhost:{__RUMBLEDB_PORT__}/jsoniq'
    response = json.loads(requests.post(url=rumbledb_url, data=resolved_query).text)

    if 'warning' in response:
            print(json.dumps(response['warning']))
    if 'values' in response:
        return response['values']
    elif 'error-message' in response:
        print(response['error-message'])
    else:
        print(response)

Test queries:
for item in jsoniq({'x': 3}, '$$$.x'):
    print(json.dumps(item))

Output: 3
for item in jsoniq([{'x': 11}, {'x': -3}, {'x': 42}], '$$$[][$$.x gt 0]'):
    print(json.dumps(item))

Output:
{"x": 11}
{"x": 42}


This is fantastic. We will consider (giving you credits) extending the pip package with an additional function along these lines. By the way, what you are doing with the $$$ symbol can in fact be done with an externally provided context item in the W3C standard, with "declare context item as array external; $$[][$$.x gt 0]" We will need, however, to make sure the RumbleDB API supports receiving a serialized object or array via the CLI or HTTP context-item param. Currently it only parses atomic values as an external context item, but this is a temporary limitation.

Another improvement suggestion: from what I understand, you build a query with parse-json() passing a serialized object (or array), e.g., parse-json("{"x": 3}").x. But in fact, any strictly well-formed JSON content can also directly be copy-pasted "as is" into JSONiq, i.e., shipping over {"x":3}.x to Rumble DB produces the same result as shipping over parse-json("{"x": 3}").x, while taking up less bandwith. In other words, you can replace $$$ directly with the results of one level of json.dumps() without the need for an extra json.dump()+parse-json().

@GhislainFourny Thanks. I've simplified the function per your second remark. I didn't manage to make the declare context item as array external;  to work though.

It looks great! Indeed, regarding the context-item prolog declaration, I meant in my previous comment that it requires a fix directly in the RumbleDB jar. I will put it on the list for a future release.

I also noticed that you use the public.rumbledb.org server (but perhaps this is only for the public code). This is fine, of course (this is a pool of micro instances automatically respawned every 24h provided for convenience and playing around). However, this means that the code above sends the request to this server and not to the server you start with your spark-submit command. If you are running your own server on your computer, you may want to use localhost in the URI.

@GhislainFourny OMG thank you! This is the explanation for this problem! It's been driving me crazy.

Very happy to help! Indeed, this is probably the explanation. At least it shows that our cloud setup is resilient and keeps running no matter what
